# Remote location loses connectivity

Tags: router, internet-connection, webcam, connection

I have a remote location that has constant internet access using DSL. The remote location only has three Linksys cameras that have internet access from a router. There is no computer on the network. The router is configured to use the DYN.org service to keep the IP address updated if the internet provider assigns a new ip address. The problem I am having is the router after a period of time stops responding to incoming ping requests and the cameras are shown offline. However, if I keep one of the cameras constantly streaming data then the connection to all the cameras works just fine all the time. How can I keep the router from appearing to be sleeping and not responding to incoming requests? The router is the Linksys WRT300N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for a keep alive setting in your router at the remote location.  You're probably running DSL over a PPPoE connection and it's timing out not seeing any traffic over the link.  By setting a keep alive period for less than the timeout period (i.e. 4 minutes if the timeout period is 5 minutes) will tell the router to send packets down the link to keep it open.  If that doesn't work you could probably script a job to periodically hit one of the cameras at your remote location to keep the link up.